# How do I edit a package?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, package, nuget-package

I am having issues with a package I have installed for a project I am working on. One of the classes that I need to use are private. How can I access these classes? Or how can I edit the project file so that I can make the changes that I need?

Answer (score 0):

You could write an extension method within your code that performs the same function as the class you need to access if you can't get at the code directly. If you can't get at the source on Github or wherever it's hosted, use a decompiler like Dotpeek or Reflector to look at the source and base your extension method on the private method.